# How Can I break a retryQueue in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

What is the purpose of retryQueue and I want to know is there anyway to `break retryQueue` in angularJS.

Please revert asap...

Comment: Care to add an example?

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you are talking about the retryQueue of Pawel Kozlowski and Peter Bacon Darwin's seed application. This queue is not part of Angular. It is necessary to repeat the requests after logging the user.

Read more about it in their book http://www.packtpub.com/angularjs-web-application-development/book